# Log Outgoing JBoss EAP 7/RESTEasy Requests

Tags: logging, jboss7.x, resteasy

Is there a way to log the outgoing HTTP requests that clients created using the ResteasyClientBuilder makes?

We're having issues with requests made by one of our services to another and want to view the headers, body etc. of the actual HTTP reqeust that RESTEasy/JBoss EAP 7 is creating/sending.

Comment: You want to log response from your service or request you created ?

for response implement : PostProcessInterceptor

Comment: I want to log the http request that my service is making to validate the headers and body.  We were able to get this information by doing a tcp dump on the server. But because the called service is using https, we had to create a proxy to pass through first so that the capture was readable. It would be much nicer if we could just log the outgoing request.

Comment: may be this will help http://blogs.adobe.com/livecycle/2011/10/how-to-enable-jboss-to-log-http-payloads.html   but it will do for all request

Also running server in debug mode also prints all request  but its too heavy

Comment: Thanks, but that blog is about logging request made TO JBoss.  I want to log requests FROM JBoss.

Comment: Are you telling that your service is making call to another service and you want to log that request which client is making ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what my question is asking.

Comment: Can you use a service like https://www.moesif.com/features? (Full disclosure I work there). They can monitor either incoming or outgoing HTTP calls.

Comment: @sdoca why don't you use the answer provided ,it logs request and response both of the client request which is placed inside a rest web service

Answer (score 2):

Resteasy Client is using Apache HTTP Client. You can set level `DEBUG` for `org.apache.http` package to see the logs:

```
<logger category="org.apache.http" use-parent-handlers="true">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to log request from client use below

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    String url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=" + "en" + "&tl=" + "hi"
            + "&dt=t&q=" + URLEncoder.encode(msg);
    client.register(new LoggingFilter());
```

Here **client.register(new LoggingFilter());**  does logging for you ,you can pass logger to it .

**Output**

```
Jan 20, 2017 1:13:48 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 1 * Sending client request on thread http-bio-127.6.45.129-8080-exec-2
   https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=hi&dt=t&q=ad
Jan 20, 2017 1:13:48 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 1 * Sending client request on thread http-bio-127.6.45.129-8080-exec-2
1 > GET https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=hi&dt=t&q=ad
Jan 20, 2017 1:13:51 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 1 * Client response received on thread http-bio-127.6.45.129-8080-exec-2
1 < 200
1 < Accept-Ranges: none
1 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
1 < Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,34"
1 < Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
1 < Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="f.txt"
1 < Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
1 < Date: Fri, 20 Jan 2017 07:43:51 GMT
1 < Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
1 < Pragma: no-cache
1 < Server: HTTP server (unknown)
1 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
1 < Vary: Accept-Encoding
1 < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
1 < X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
1 < X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Same can be done by editing web.xml
as below

```
    <web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
         <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
         <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
     </init-param>

 <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.webspherenotes.rest.ContactApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>

  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  That is a code change and I was hoping to just be able to turn set something in JBoss that turns on/off logging of the requests.

Comment: edited the answer class for init param may differ for newer jersey version

Comment: Updating the web.xml is the same as a code change. It requires a build/deploy of the application.  As stated previously, I was looking for a general way to turn the logging on/off in JBoss EAP.  Also, JBoss uses RESTEasy, not Jersey.

Comment: Then you can go for a custom filter class instead of com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter and in it you can have mechanism for on/off ,it would require code change once only and you can add this code in different jar and add it is module dependency in case you wan separate code bases for such logging.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts to help, but I was looking for an option in JBoss EAP to log outgoing HTTP requests in general.  I am NOT looking for a way to enable logging in a specific application.  I was already aware of serveral ways to do this.  It could very well that the answer to my question is is that it cannot be done.  I can accept that.