# Log requests sent with ResteasyClient

Tags: java, resteasy

In our project, we are using `Resteasy` to implement the client of a REST-API. Our code looks something like:

```
ResteasyClient client = ...;
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("api-path");
MyProxyClass proxy = target.proxy(MyProxyClass.class);
```

where `MyProxyClass` is defined like this:

```
public interface MyProxyClass {
    @POST
    @Path("/path")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response myMethod(MyPayloadClass payload);
}
```

`proxy` is then used to submit requests to the REST-API, e.g.

```
MyPayloadClass payload = ...;
proxy.myMethod(payload);
```

In order to debug our application, we would like to log the *exact* request that `RestEasy` sends to the external REST-API. In particular, we would like to see the exact headers and JSON payload so that we can test the requests with an external tool like `curl`. Notice that, since the marshalling is done automatically / implicitly by the library, we have no access to the entities being sent with the request.

Is there such a possibility? After a lot of searching and reading in the documentation, we found no hint on how to log requests with `RestEasy`.

Comment: You can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707741/log-outgoing-jboss-eap-7-resteasy-requests

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666406/logging-request-and-response-in-one-place-with-jax-rs) fits better